# c program - struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have question in relation to the line `rtc_set_alarm(RTC_0, (RTC[RTC_0].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));`
in `main()` below.

In the second argument of `rtc_set_alarm()` I understand `RTC` to be a pointer of `struct` type that points to the address 0xB0000400. It then access the first member of the struct by using `.rtc_ccvr`.

My question is, why is it necessary to use `RTC_0` of the `enum rtc_t`.

I would of thought that it would be just `RTC.rtc_ccvr`?

Apologies, I'm new to struct pointers.

```
** Number of RTC controllers. */
typedef enum { RTC_0 = 0, RTC_NUM } rtc_t;

/** RTC register map. */
typedef struct {
    RW uint32_t rtc_ccvr;    /**< Current Counter Value Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_cmr;         /**< Current Match Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_clr;         /**< Counter Load Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_ccr;         /**< Counter Control Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_stat;    /**< Interrupt Status Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_rstat;  /**< Interrupt Raw Status Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_eoi;         /**< End of Interrupt Register */
    RW uint32_t rtc_comp_version; /**< End of Interrupt Register */
} rtc_reg_t;


/* RTC register base address. */
#define RTC_BASE (0xB0000400)

/* RTC register block. */
#define RTC ((rtc_reg_t *)RTC_BASE)


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

//function declaration
int qm_rtc_set_alarm(const rtc_t rtc, const uint32_t alarm_val)

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(void)
{
#define ALARM (RTC_ALARM_MINUTE / 6)
rtc_set_alarm(RTC_0, (RTC[RTC_0].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

its so you can have more than one RTC. To access the second one you would use

```
rtc_set_alarm(RTC_1, (RTC[RTC_1].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));
```

Its nothing to do with the fields inside the struct, its which struct to use

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the code a bit. You probably know that an `enum` is just a way of giving names to numbers, so every value in an `enum` translates to an integer - `RTC_0` is exactly the same as `0` in this code. So the call:

```
rtc_set_alarm(RTC_0, (RTC[RTC_0].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));
```

is identical to

```
rtc_set_alarm(RTC_0, (RTC[0].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));
```

Now what is `RTC`? It's a pointer to a struct, but there is no information about how many register sets of `rtc_reg_t` type there are. So if you have three such register sets, it would be equally valid to do:

```
rtc_set_alarm(RTC_0, (RTC[2].rtc_ccvr + ALARM));
```

So the purpose of writing `RTC[RTC_0]` is to explicitly access the first RTC controller's register, and to access others in the same way, if there were any. In your example there is only one, and it's possible that `rtc_set_alarm` checks that you're not accessing index `RTC_NUM` or beyond.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The first register is `rtc_ccvr`. So I would of thought using `RTC.rtc_ccvr` ensures the first register is accessed. @pm100 suggests that it used for the RTC controller and not the register?

Comment: @logitech mouse I've improved the wording of my answer - yes, the `0` is for accessing the first *set* of registers, that is, the registers of the first controller.